# How to recognize specific exception in Delphi

Tags: delphi

Most of the time I'm relying on the ClassName and the Message of the exception to decide what to do in case of an error:

```
      AddDebugMessage('GetExcelValues: Exception '+e.ClassName+' with message '+e.Message+' while getting values from sheet '+TaskRecs[TaskNr].SheetName,Error)
```

But now I'm working with Excel OLE and Exception messages seem to have been translated (into Dutch in my case). So looking at the Exception message seems to be out of the question.

Is there a better way to find out what exception is being raised?

Comment: It might just be the wording, but "Most of the time I'm relying on the ClassName [...]" indicates that you are using `E.ClassName` to see what kind of exception `E` is. That's wrong. You should use its class instead, e.g. `on E: EFrogException do` or `if E is EFrogException then`.

Comment: I don't understand the question: `Exception.ClassName` should still be identifyable and unbound to translation issues. Or is the same Exception used and different messages may occur?

Comment: @AmigoJack: I think the class is always `EOleException`, but the OP should clarify this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many exception classes have more members to help describe the error. For Excel (or other OLE handling), you can get the error code like this:

```
try
    // Excel handling removed 
except
    on E: EOleException do begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add(E.Message);
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Error code 0x' + IntToHex(E.ErrorCode, 8));
        Exit;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. BTW, I know that it is better to look at the class itself instead of the classname but looking at the message was killing...

Comment: And, as always, the way to discover this is to consult [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Win.ComObj.EOleSysError.ErrorCode).